# How to set time zone to datetime now in Python?

Tags: python

I would like to call current datetime.now() with GMT +0 (UK) time zone. My workstation is in other timezone.

How to do it?

Comment: Per https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now you can pass a `tz` to it - did you try that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

**Before Python 3.6** you can use [pytz](https://pypi.org/project/pytz/) (external package)

```py
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone    

print(datetime.now(timezone('Europe/London')))
```

---

**Update** according @WolfgangKuehn comment

**Starting from Python 3.6** you can use  [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/zoneinfo.html) via standard library (>=3.9) or backport instead of [pytz](https://pypi.org/project/pytz/)

```py
from datetime import datetime
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo

print(datetime.now(ZoneInfo('Europe/London')))
```

Comment: Downvote for suggesting the deprecated _pytz_ in __2022__. Please use the [Standard Library](https://docs.python.org/3/library)

Comment: Thanks @WolfgangKuehn! I have updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone
print(datetime.now(timezone.utc))
```